# Enterprise Email Servers Suggestions

Tags: email, email-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exchange server replacement that runs on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/35842/exchange-server-replacement-that-runs-on-linux)

Hi StackOverflow,

I'm posting here because of the continued quality feedback throughout the time I've been a member.

My goal (hopefully) is to obtain information, pros/cons, reviews, or any other feedback regarding the following Enterprise Email Systems.

```
* Zimbra
* Scalix
* Mirapoint
* Communigate Pro
```

Any responses, both positive and negative, will be beneficial in my research for our company's new email system.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: "throughout the time I've been a member" - so all day then?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Zimbra.

If you ask specific questions I will try to answer.

On the other hand I think if you really want to know. You should install them and try out (for the best on your machine) or get a testdrive account for a starter.