# Zimbra Alternative Open source application

Tags: email-server, open-source

I'm looking for an open source alternative for zimbra which supports outlook and thunderbird as pop and smtp clients. I don't need collaboration suite.

If anyone can suggest or share their experience on MTA?

Thanks.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this ServerFault thread titled "[Exchange server replacement that runs on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/35842/exchange-server-replacement-that-runs-on-linux/)"

Assuming you want one that runs on Linux, you have

- [Kerio](http://www.kerio.com/)
- [Scalix](http://www.scalix.com/)
- [OpenXchange](http://www.open-xchange.com/)
- [Kolab](http://www.kolab.org/)
- [Linagora](http://www.linagora.com/English)
- [Zarafa](http://www.zarafa.com/)
- [Communigate Pro](http://www.communigate.com/) (Not open, but hey...)

And more that remain to be explored. If the server support open standards like SMTP and POP3, then there will be no problem with using Outlook, Thunderbird or any other standard client.

Comment: Kerio runs on Linux just fine.

Comment: @SvenW Well paint me purple and call me Barney, so it does! Post edited.

Comment: @WesleyDvaid These are a long list and there community versions support small number of clients on outlook. I have 350 outlook clients on peak time while total email accounts are around 500+. I am still looking for open source email management suite.

Comment: @SilentPlayer: You need explicit Outlook support only when you want to use groupware functionality like Contacts and Calendars. Outlook can use IMAP just fine if only E-Mail is needed.

Comment: @SilentPlayer All of those products can easily scale into tens of thousands of users. Your users using Outlook doesn't effect anything unless they also want to use shared calendars, like SvenW said.

Answer (score 1):

MTA is Mail Transfer Agent (SMTP portion). MTA is maybe 5% of what Zimbra does.

I've been using Cyrus IMAP & POP for years, works great with both Outlook and Thunderbird.

Comment: I need to managed domains with emails accounts including aliases and plenty of other options.. just like Zimbra provides.

Comment: @SilentPlayer: Any decent MTA will handle aliases and plenty of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Without a collab suite, all you need is a simple MTA and POP/IMAP server, plus maybe a management GUI for it all. A typical solution is postfix and Cyrus, with the addition of ISPconfig and the likes.